# After cloning from Github, where is the repo's .git folder?

Tags: git

I try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/red23jordan/try_git.git
```

After that, the try_git folder is downloaded to my PC.
But why there is no .git folder??
I want to go back to previous version, how to go back?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .git folder is inside the try_git folder; depending on the settings of your file manager and operating system, it might be hidden (in that case, you'll have to find the option to enabled "Display hidden files", or similar)